# PHP desktop how to change the main window icon

Tags: php, phpdesktop

I am starting to use [PHP desktop](https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/Download-Chrome) to create a desktop application and it works great, just want to know if there's any settings to change the main windows icon, i know to change the pop-up windows icon can be change on settings.json, but i cannot find any settings to change the main windows.

[image]

Note: im using Inno Compiler to distribute my application, but the compiler only change the set-up icon not the main application.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP Desktop, but you can try replacing the icon.ico file with your own.

Comment: Well if you look at the respiratory of PHP desktop on github there's no .ico file inside. i updated my question including using inno compiler software to distribute my application.

Comment: [Yes, there is](https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/blob/master/phpdesktop-chrome/icon.ico)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out D.R but i am using the package with a PHP 5.6 version inside.

Comment: Ok so after looking i found that the package with PHP 5.4 has a main window icon settings, so i copied the settings to PHP 5.6 and successfully changed it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem, the solution is provided by the creator -

If you would like to change the icon that is embedded in the executable file then do the following steps:

Download Resource Hacker and run it.
From the "File" menu select open, navigate and choose "phpdesktop-msie.exe" (or "phpdesktop-chrome.exe").

On the left side there should be a tree control, expand "/Icon Group/128/1033", right click on the "1033", select "Replace Resource..." and replace that resource with your icon.

That's it, save it and see the changes by running the executable file.
When you change icon embedded in the executable file you do not need to set it anymore in the settings file.

Comment: Thanks, I have to close file explorer after changing otherwise it is showing me old icon.

Comment: very nice answer.

Comment: Very nice answer. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

[image: php desktop add icon]

Put **.ico** image inside your folder and edit `setting.json` file like below

```
"main_window": {
    "title": "----",
    "icon": "ico.ico",
     ----},
```