# PHP desktop how to change the icon

Tags: php, github, phpdesktop

I am starting to use PHP desktop to create a desktop application and it works great, just want to know if there's any settings to change the icon,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/312Pr.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp5Yj.png)

i know to change the main window icon can be change on settings.json, but i cannot find any settings to change the .exe icon window.
Please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP desktop how to change the main window icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990478/php-desktop-how-to-change-the-main-window-icon)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - long story short you can't, at least using the config files or anything.

With that said, you CAN rename the .exe anything you like and it'll work just fine, and change the icon using various programs.  Freeware 'Resource Hacker' http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/ can replace the .ico in said exe super easy.  (Open it, look for 'Icon' in the left panel and click on the entry within, then go to 'Action' in the toolbar and choose 'Replace Icon'.  Pick the alternative then make sure to save when you're done.